# How to find if a document exists in the database using xquery

Tags: xquery

I am using xquery over BaseX XML Database. Say, I have the following documents stored in my database: doc1, doc2, doc3.

What Xquery do I use to check the existence of a given document. I tried the following:

declare variable $doc_name as xs:string external;

return boolean($doc_name)

I expected it to work as follows:
if doc_name = doc1 return true
if doc_name = nodoc return false

But, I see an exception:

java.io.IOException: Stopped at line 3, column 7: 
[XPST0003] Unexpected end of query: 'boolean("doc1")'.

I also tried return

- return fn:exists($doc_name) and
- return fn:doc-available(doc_uri)

These do not work either. I see the same end of query exception. What is the correct way of checking a document's existence?

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use the standard XPath/XQuery function [`doc-available()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-doc-available)** .

From the Spec:

`fn:doc-available($uri as xs:string?) as xs:boolean`

**Summary**: The function returns true if and only if the function call `fn:doc($uri)` would return a document node.

If `$uri` is an empty sequence, this function returns `false`.

If a call on `fn:doc($uri)` would return a document node, this function returns `true`.

If `$uri` is not a valid URI according to the rules applied by the implementation of `fn:doc`, an error is raised [err:FODC0005].

Otherwise, this function returns `false`.

If this function returns `true`, then calling `fn:doc($uri)` within the same ·execution scope· must return a document node. However, if non-stable processing has been selected for the `fn:doc` function, this guarantee is lost.

Comment: Yes, Please see my edit. I tried this too. return fn:doc-available(http://top.cs.vt.edu:8080/editionbuilder/feeds/feed_sony_dot_vibh_at_gmail_dot_com_feed4) returns false. But, you can see that the document is located at the given url.

Comment: @sony: Does the process have enough privileges for such `http:` protocol usage?

Comment: @sony: What if you try without the `return` ?